# Forking in C program causes parent print out to be duplicated

Tags: c, fork

I'm having some trouble understanding the output of this program. After running this program the output ends up being `0Yo!1Yo!Yo!2Yo!Yo!Yo!3Yo!Yo!Yo!Yo!4Yo!Yo!Yo!Yo!Yo!5Yo!Yo!Yo!Yo!Yo!5`. As you can see the number of `Yo!`s being printed by the parent process increases for each pass of the `while` loop. I was hoping to get some clarification as to why this was happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (fork() && i < 5) {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Yo!");
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're copying the buffer. Flush it before forking.

```c
fflush( STDOUT );
```

Answer (score 1):

Output to `stdout` is line buffered by default when the process is attached to a terminal.  The output produced by the `printf` statements is buffered and the state of the output stream is duplicated by `fork()`, hence whenever the stream gets flushed in each process (when returning from `main()` at the latests), the output appears duplicated.

You should flush the `stdout` stream after the `printf` statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (fork() && i < 5) {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Yo!");
        flush(stdout);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```

You can also make `stdout` unbuffered at the start of the program and this state will be duplicated for child processes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    for (int i = 0; fork() && i < 5; i++) {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Yo!");
    }
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```